# When should I remove a UserControl from the message filter?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm implementing a `UserControl` which implements `IMessageFilter`.  It calls `Application.AddMessageFilter` in its constructor.  I'd like to remove it from the message filter in its `Dispose(bool disposing)` method, but I don't know whether to place the call to `Application.RemoveMessageFilter` inside the test (so it gets called when `disposing` is true) or whether I should call it outside the test (so it gets called whenever the method is called).

Which is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may only call other managed objects when disposing and not when finalizing since there is no guarantee that the other referenced objects have not already been finalized.  This means that you should call RemoveMessageFilter only when `disposing` is true.